# Integer Partitions and distinguishable permutations

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, multinomial-coefficients

I'm not a mathematician but I'm faced with a problem where I can't find an
answer, also because I do not know what I shall ask for:

I have to deal with partitions of an integer k, only small values, up to 30
at most. If we write this partitions down, lets say for k=4, we have p(k) = 5,
namely:

```
1,1,1,1
2,1,1
2,2
3,1
4
```

So far, so good.

Now we have to build distinguishable permutations with these partitions, where the length of the permutation l is always greater or equal than k,
let's say l = 6 for this explanation. (so they are filled up with 0s)

My task now is to find the *sum s(k,l) of distinguishable permutations to be build out of the given partitions*, for the given length

```
1,1,1,1,0,0
2,1,1,0,0,0
2,2,0,0,0,0
3,1,0,0,0,0
4,0,0,0,0,0
```

I have learned in my school-days (it's long ago), that this could be achieved
with the multinomial coefficient, that I have to apply for every single
partition. Finally I have to sum it up, and my problem would be solved.

I can do this - with the help of a computer program.

But, and this is my question, is there a more mathematical solution?
Does anyone know whether there is a term or a 
definition or a function name what I would like to calculate?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: The term you are looking for is [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of integer $k$, rather than partitions.  In other words, summations to $k$ where the order of summands matters.  As Matt Samuel points out, these are pretty easy to count, much easier than partitions at any rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same as the number of sequences of nonnegative integers $x_1,\ldots,x_l$ whose sum is $k$, or equivalently the number of sequences of positive integers of this length whose sum is $k+l$. This is the number of ways to choose $l-1$ partitions between $k+l$ elements to divide them into $l$ nonempty groups. The answer is
$$\binom{k+l-1}{l-1}$$

Comment: Matt, I do not understand it well (up till now) what you have written, but it seems to be right. Great!

Comment: @Excalibur though you came across it in a roundabout way, luckily the final result is a very common problem. The method is often called "stars and bars" if you want to look it up.